# adding namespace while creating a XML document using Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I need to create a XML document using Python but i am unable to figure out 
how to add a

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

And how to add the namespace elements to the document tag

```
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:2013:008.001.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <page1 xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:2013:008.001.02" </page1>
</Document>
```

Any examples please

Comment: Have you looked at the lxml tutorial http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces - which part there do you ot understand so that we can try to explain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To output xml declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, use `lxml.etree.tostring` with `xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8'` as argument.

To add namespace element, pass `nsmap` argument when creating element.

```
>>> import lxml.etree
>>>
>>> nsmap = {
...     None: "urn:iso:std:iso:2013:008.001.02",
...     'xsi': "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
... }
>>> root = lxml.etree.Element('Document', nsmap=nsmap)
>>> lxml.etree.SubElement(root, 'page1')
<Element page1 at 0x2ad8af8>
>>> print lxml.etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', pretty_print=True)
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:2013:008.001.02">
  <page1/>
</Document>

>>>
```