# Creating XML document with multiple namespaces and xsi:type attribute

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

How can I create this XML structure with Python and lxml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4" xmlns:cce11="http://www.sat.gob.mx/ComercioExterior11" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/ComercioExterior11 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/ComercioExterior11/ComercioExterior11.xsd" Version="4.0" Fecha="2023-12-27T11:53:50">
    <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="XAXX010101XXX" Nombre="COMPANY" RegimenFiscal="601"/>
    <cfdi:Receptor Rfc="XEXX010101XXX" Nombre="COMPANY" DomicilioFiscalReceptor="00000" RegimenFiscalReceptor="601" UsoCFDI="G01"/>
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="00000000" NoIdentificacion="XXXXX" Cantidad="1.000000" ClaveUnidad="EA" Unidad="PIEZA" Descripcion="XXXXX" ValorUnitario="1.00" Importe="1.00" ObjetoImp="00">
            <cfdi:Impuestos>
                <cfdi:Traslados>
                    <cfdi:Traslado Base="1.00" Importe="1.00" Impuesto="000" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.000000"/>
                </cfdi:Traslados>
            </cfdi:Impuestos>
        </cfdi:Concepto>
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Impuestos TotalImpuestosTrasladados="1.00">
        <cfdi:Traslados>
            <cfdi:Traslado Base="1.00" Importe="1.00" Impuesto="000" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.000000"/>
            <cfdi:Traslado Base="1.00" Importe="1.00" Impuesto="000" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.000000"/>
        </cfdi:Traslados>
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

This structure is used for Mexican invoices.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where are you stuck? Please ask about one specific problem at a time. Similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19525627/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46405690/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/62395506/407651, https://stackoverflow.com/q/74861801/407651

Comment: Thank you @mzjn
My problem is with the display order of root node attributes Version and Fecha. With my approach they are displayed between xsi and xsi:schemaLocation and this cause an error when validating the XML structure.
Here is what I've tried:

Comment: qname = etree.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "schemaLocation")
cfdi_base = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4"
cfdiBASE = "{%s}" % cfdi_base
ns_cce = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/ComercioExterior11"
ns_xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
NSMAP = {'cfdi' : cfdi_base,'cce11':ns_cce,'xsi':ns_xsi}
CFDI = etree.Element(cfdiBASE + "Comprobante", {qname: "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/ComExt11 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/ComExt11/ComExt11.xsd"}, nsmap=NSMAP, Version="4", Fecha="...")

Comment: To explain the problem and to show what you have tried, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77730066/edit) the question.

Answer (score -2):

Using a Powershell script.  I hardcoded the values.  The total I also hardcoded.

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq 

$filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$emisorRfc = 'XAXX010101XXX'
$receptorRfc = 'XEXX010101XXX'
$nombre = 'COMPANY' 
$regimenFiscal = '601'

$domicilioFiscalReceptor = '00000'
$regimenFiscalReceptor = '601' 
$usoCFDI = 'G01'

$claveProdServ = '00000000'
$noIdentificacion = 'XXXXX' 
$cantidad = '1.000000'
$claveUnidad = 'EA' 
$unidad = 'PIEZA' 
$descripcion = 'XXXXX' 
$valorUnitario = '1.00' 
$importe = '1.00' 
$objetoImp = '00'

$base = '1.00' 
$importe = '1.00' 
$impuesto = '000' 
$tipoFactor = 'Tasa' 
$tasaOCuota = '0.000000'

$ident = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4" xmlns:cce11="http://www.sat.gob.mx/ComercioExterior11" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/ComercioExterior11 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/ComercioExterior11/ComercioExterior11.xsd" Version="4.0">
</cfdi:Comprobante>
'@

$xDoc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Parse($ident)
$root = $xDoc.Root

$date = [DateTime]::Now
$dateStr = $date.ToString('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')
$fecha = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Fecha'), $dateStr)
$root.Add($fecha)

$nscfdi = $root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix('cfdi')
$nscce11 = $root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix('cce11')
$nsxsi = $root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix('xsdi')

$emisor = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get($nscfdi + 'Emisor'))

$emisorRfcAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('RFC'), $emisorRfc)
$emisor.Add($emisorRfcAttr)

$emisorNombre = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Nombre'), $nombre)
$emisor.Add($emisorNombre)

$emisorRegimen = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('RegimenFiscal'), $regimenFiscal)
$emisor.Add($emisorRegimen)

$root.Add($emisor)

$receptor = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get($nscfdi + 'Receptor'))

$receptorRfcAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('RFC'), $receptorRfc)
$receptor.Add($receptorRfcAttr)

$receptor.Add($emisorNombre)

$receptorDomicilioFiscal = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('DomicilioFiscalReceptor'), $domicilioFiscalReceptor)
$receptor.Add($receptorDomicilioFiscal)

$receptorRegimenFiscal = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('RegimenFiscalReceptor'), $regimenFiscalReceptor)
$receptor.Add($receptorRegimenFiscal)

$receptorUsoCFDI = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('UsoCFDI'), $usoCFDI)
$receptor.Add($receptorUsoCFDI)

$root.Add($receptor)

$conceptos = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get($nscfdi + 'Conceptos'))

$concepto = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get($nscfdi + 'Concepto'))

$claveProdServAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('ClaveProdServ'), $claveProdServ)
$concepto.Add($claveProdServAttr)

$noIdentificacionAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('NoIdentificacion'), $noIdentificacion)
$concepto.Add($noIdentificacionAttr)

$cantidadAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Cantidad'), $cantidad)
$concepto.Add($cantidadAttr)

$claveUnidadAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('ClaveUnidad'), $claveUnidad)
$concepto.Add($claveUnidadAttr)

$unidadAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Unidad'), $unidad)
$concepto.Add($unidadAttr)

$descripcionAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Descripcion'), $descripcion)
$concepto.Add($descripcionAttr)

$valorUnitarioAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('ValorUnitario'), $valorUnitario)
$concepto.Add($valorUnitarioAttr)

$importeAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Importe'), $importe)
$concepto.Add($importeAttr)

$objetoImpAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('ObjetoImp'), $objetoImp)
$concepto.Add($objetoImpAttr)

$impuestos = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get($nscfdi + 'Impuestos'))

$traslados = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get($nscfdi + 'Traslados'))

$traslado = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get($nscfdi + 'Traslado'))

$baseAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Base'), $base)
$traslado.Add($baseAttr)

$importeAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Importe'), $importe)
$traslado.Add($importeAttr)

$impuestoAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('Impuesto'), $impuesto)
$traslado.Add($impuestoAttr)

$tipoFactorAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('TipoFactor'), $tipoFactor)
$traslado.Add($tipoFactorAttr)

$tasaOCuotaAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('TasaOCuota'), $tasaOCuota)
$traslado.Add($tasaOCuotaAttr)

$traslados.Add($traslado)

$impuestos.Add($traslados)

$concepto.Add($impuestos)

$conceptos.Add($concepto)

$root.Add($conceptos)

$impuestos = [System.Xml.Linq.XElement]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get($nscfdi + 'Impuestos'))

$totalImpuestosTrasladados = '1.00'

$totalImpuestosTrasladadosAttr = [System.Xml.Linq.XAttribute]::new([System.Xml.Linq.XName]::Get('TotalImpuestosTrasladados'), $totalImpuestosTrasladados)
$impuestos.Add($totalImpuestosTrasladadosAttr)

$root.Add($impuestos)

$xDoc.Save($filename)
```

Comment: The question was ...with Python and lxml ...!

Comment: @Hermann12 : Alternate solutions are allowed at this website.

Comment: [@jdweng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015238/jdweng) the question is about python, if you can read. Therefore your answer isn’t suitable, I think. It could be that the OP works on Linux, or iOS.

Comment: @Hermann12 : There is nothing wrong with post alternate answer especially since nobody posted a python solution.  Do not guess.  PS can run on Linux and Mac.  PS is written in Net Library.